# Is the following join equivalent?

Tags: sql, outer-join

I'm a little confused regarding the left and right join operators.

```
select  *
from    <left table> lt
    left join <right table> rt on lt.pk = rt.fk
```

I've always been a little confused as to exactly which side the "left" side of the join is. The table on the left side of the "left join" keywords ... is that "the left table" or is the table on the left side of the on clause the left table as in the one that's on the left side of the equal sign. I've read articles that indicate that it's supposed to be

However ... now considering the following select statement ...

```
select  *
from    <some table> st
    inner join <left table> lt on st.pk = lt.fk
    left join <right table r on rt.fk = st.pk
```

In the above bit of code is the left table ? One would assume so considering the previous statments however because of the ambiguity or the unclarity (because it actually is not directly left) ... I would think that it would make more sense for the "left table" to be specified in the on clause.

So every bit of me seems to be fighting that logic ... and I need a little bit of clarification ... please and thanks.

Comment: So actually ... I do like the answer from possible duplicate. Provided by Ruakh - The "left" side is actually the result of joining departments and employee. Joins are left-associative, so x JOIN y JOIN z is equivalent to (x JOIN y) JOIN z. - So the left side is the result of the inner join between some table and left table ... is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first table listed is the one from which all rows will be returned. The table that is named after the `LEFT JOIN` will return only rows which match the first table and will return NULL values where no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

In general - no, because you introduce one more filter table st.
But **IF** every row of lt has the corresponding and **the only** row in st - yes, the amount of rows will be the same, a collection of columns will differ. But the resultset from the first query will be a subset (difference only in columns from st table) of resultset from 2nd query